# VSTS how to create a new user field

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to create a new user field in VSTS similar to Assigned To. Assigned To is of type "Text (single line)" but acts like a user search box or picklist, I want this functionality in a new custom field.

From the GUI this does not seem possible as there is no option to create a user field or restrict a text field to users. The [rest api documentation for fields](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/fields) does not mention creating fields and when I have tried to experiment with it it tells me that POST/PUT/PATCH are not supported by the method.

A multi-user field similar to what Jira can do would be great as well if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The REST API is used to get workitem filed not for creating or adding a new field. There's no such kind of REST API to do that.

For VSTS, it doesn't support to add a custom field like Assign to. The custom field doesn't support to add any workitem rules. Select "Text (single line)" type, it couldn't load that user information when you enter its username. You could vote the user voice here about your request: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/17907571-add-a-custom-field-like-assign-to

Comment: From my understanding this is supported by TFS but not by VSTS. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41397660/98145) also claims this and I have seen if mentioned in a couple other places. When I have tried to import a WIT I get the same error mentioned there. When I do a WIT export it does not contain any of my custom fields as well.

Comment: @nash Sorry for the mistake, I confused it with another thread post.  Yes, VSTS doesn't support with witadmin, it can't import. I have edited my reply. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the field type should be "Identity" in Azure DevOps browser version. This type is used to search for a user, and show as a drop-down list.
[image: reference]