# ProvisioningImportEventsCallback error while trying to import Work item type definition

Tags: tfs, tfs-2017

I try this command in `%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer>`

```
witadmin importwitd /collection:http://server/tfs/collction /p:project /f:"workitem.xml"
```

and get this in red:

> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.ProvisioningImportEventsCallback

(Edit:) The exportwitd command works without error, and I am trying to import the same XML that I just exported, to the same WIT.

I found some references to this error, but most solutions seem to say not to use that with VSTS:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6d797a4c-9f87-458a-9572-cb7552c3d607/witadmin-returns-error?forum=TFService
[Unable to import work item type definition: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.ProvisioningImportEventsCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396479/unable-to-import-work-item-type-definition-microsoft-teamfoundation-workitemtra)

But I'm not using VSTS, I'm using TFS 2017 Update 3.

I've tried clearing my TFS cache under `%AppData%\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache` and I've also tried clearing my credential vault.

I've also tried using the [WorkItemTypeCollection.Import Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb140406%28v%3Dvs.120%29) but it yields the same error.

Also, the import is successful if I use my account with Server Administration permissions, which suggests it's a permission error, but I'm stumped by the error message. What does it mean?

Comment: Is your TFS upgraded before? Are you able to export a work item type with `witadmin exportwitd`?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Yes, our TFS has been upgraded before. Yes, I am able to export with witadmin exportwitd - question updated.

Comment: Weird issue. Are you able to reproduce this issue on another client machine?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT  When I try it on another machine, after trying it a few times, I get the same behavior. (At first, it was not succeeding at all - no output at all with that account, for ANY witadmin command.)  With the privileged account, everything works normally.

Comment: It seems you are getting permission issue, but the error message is not correct. Am I right?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Yes, it seems to be a permission problem, but I'm not sure.  I'm wondering why I'm receiving that error message, and what does it mean, or how can I start to troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0):

To export or list work item types, you must be a member of the **Project Administrators** group or have your **View project-level information** permission set to **Allow**.

To destroy, import, or rename work item types, you must be a member of the **Team Foundation Administrators** security group or the **Project Administrators** security group.

You may check the account permission.

Comment: Does this mean the ProvisioningImportsCallback is expected behaviour?  Should I catch that exception and output some message similar to what you have said, or are there other situations where this ProvisioningImportsCallback error is thrown?  Is there any documentation on it?

Comment: Sorry, I could not find any documentation on this error message. I'm not able to reproduce this issue either. Since you don't have this issue once use another account, so you could check the permission first.